# Sometimes $(this) is not working with AJAX success code

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress AJAX for showing some results.
The function is working very well but while showing the result $(this) is not working.

My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.review_status").live("click", function () {

        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        dataString = 'id=' + id;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $ajax_status_url; ?>",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $(this).text(html);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

In that AJAX is not give me proper result.

Comment: you are missing the action value so no functions are being called at all. i think live is also depreciated

Comment: In ajax response the scope of the $(this) is updated, so declare some variable for $(this) and use it allover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead of above code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("a.review_status").live("click", function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    dataString = 'id=' + id;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $ajax_status_url; ?>",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $(element).text(html);
        }
    });

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a change in context in the callback inside the ajax success.  The reference to `this` inside the success funtion points to the success function itself and not to the element that was clicked on.

A way around this is to store a reference to `this` as `self`.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.review_status").live("click", function () {

        var self = this;

        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        dataString = 'id=' + id;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $ajax_status_url; ?>",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $(self).text(html);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try jQuery instead of $

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("a.review_status").live("click", function () {
    var element = jQuery(this);
    var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    dataString = 'id=' + id;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $ajax_status_url; ?>",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            jQuery(element).text(html);
        }
    });

});
});
</script>
```